# Higher Order of Function (Map)

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions, map-function

I am slightly confused by `map` in python. The function for `map`accepts 2 parameters: `map(function, variables).

Why is the code below able to take in `multiply` and `add` as variables but the second code isn't able to? In a usual case, `multiply` should be passed in in as a function, check out range.

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * x

def add(x):
    return x + x

funcs = [multiply, add]

for i in range (1, 5):
    value = list(map(lambda x: x(i), funcs))
    print(value)
```

This is the second code:

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * x

def add(x):
    return x + x

funcs = (add, multiply)
multi_func = (multiply)

for i in range (1, 5):
    value = list(map(lambda x: x(i), multi_func))
    print(value)
```

Is it possible to make use of 1 function and still use for in range?

Using range:

```
map(multiply, range(1, 5))
```

Comment: Try `multi_func = (multiply,)`

Comment: It works! But why isn't it on the left-hand-side of the map's parameter since is a function?

Comment: I think is because it takes in as a tuple? But I am still shocked on how it is able to swap places. (When I look at using range method)

Comment: map takes a callable and an iterable of arguments. The callable you gave it, `lambda x: x(i)` simply *calls it's argument*, and the iterable you were *trying* to give it is an iterable of callables (i.e. functions)

Answer (score 3):

`map` applies its first argument, which is a function, to each element of the iterable which is the second argument. The function is applied lazily. That means it's done only when you iterate over the map object, e.g., when you create a list of of it.

Let's take a look at your first code. `funcs = [multiply, add]` creates a list, which is iterable, of two elements. Both elements are functions. This is normal in Python, because functions are just regular objects, and can be passed around, assigned, have attributes, etc. The loop

```
for i in range (1, 5):
    value = list(map(lambda x: x(i), funcs))
    print(value)
```

Repeats form 1 to 4. At each iteration it maps `lambda x: x(i)` to the functions in `funcs`. When `i = 1`, the map ends up doing `multiply(1), add(1)`. When `i = 2`, it's `multiply(2), add(2)`, and so on.

The second code doesn't work because of a typo. `(x)` is just `x`, but `(x,)` is a one-element tuple whose first element is `x`. `map` *requires* the second argument to be iterable, so passing in a function won't do. If you want to map to a single function, you need to supply an iterable with one element: `multi_func = (multiply,)`.

Once corrected, the second version will print `multiply(1)` when `i = 1`, `multiply(2)` when `i = 2`, etc.

Something like `list(map(multiply, range(1, 5)))` will in fact be an easier way to write the second version. You can also do something similar with the first code, using `zip`:

```
zip(map(func, range(1, 5)) for func in funcs)
```